# How to get data from node.js when using a post request in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I am creating a mern authentication project and am stuck on a problem. When the information is sent in my register page an add user function is called on the front end

```
async function addUser(user) {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };
    try {
      await axios.post("/users/register", user, config);
    } catch (err) {}
  }
```

Which calls this function in my back end

```
exports.addUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { name, email, password } = req.body;
    let errors = [];
    // Check required fields
    if (!name || !email || !password) {
      errors.push("All Fields Need To Be Filled");
    }
    //Check Password Length
    if (password.length < 6) {
      errors.push("Password Needs To Be At Least 6 Characters Long");
    }
    if (errors.length > 0) {
      return res.status(201).json({
        success: false,
        errors,
      });
    } else {
      return res.status(201).json({
        success: true,
        data: req.body,
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      error,
    });
  }
};
```

And my route

```
router.route("/register").post(addUser)
```

My question is how to get the json from the node.js function in react.js. For example if there is an error how do I get this

```
      return res.status(201).json({
        success: false,
        errors,
```

in my front end. Since this is not a get request I can't access the errors with

```
      const res = await axios.get("/");
```

If anybody knows what to do it would mean a lot if you helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I would recommend changing the code as a response of `201` is considered a successful "Created" response ([mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)).

Then, if you are using axios, you need to create an interceptor in your frontend side that will handle the response errors. Check the documentation [here](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors).

Basically you can leave the response part empty, and then throw an exception in the error function so you can handle it from the place you are making the call.

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => response,
    (error) => {
        // you can handle the error here or throw an error
        throw error;
    }
})
```

I recommend that you leave the interceptor and the base axios call in a separate file so it's easier for you to handle the calls and the interceptor.